# Find if one list is a subsequence of another

Tags: python, performance, beginner, algorithm, array

So the problem of verifying if a list is a subsequence of another came up in a discussion, and I wrote code that seems to work (I haven't rigorously tested it).

**IsSubequence.py**

```py
def is_subsequence(lst1, lst2):
    """
        *   Finds if a list is a subsequence of another.

        *   Params:
            *   `lst1` (`list`): The candidate subsequence.
            *   `lst2` (`list`): The parent list.
        *   Return:
            *   (`bool`): A boolean variable indicating whether `lst1` is a subsequence of `lst2`.
    """
    l1, l2 = len(lst1), len(lst2)
    if l1 > l2:  #`l1` must be <= `l2` for `lst1` to be a subsequence of `lst2`.
        return False
    i = j = 0
    d1, d2 = l1, l2
    while i < l1 and j < l2:
        while lst1[i] != lst2[j]:
            j += 1
            d2 -= 1
            if d1 > d2:  #At this point, `lst1` cannot a subsequence of `lst2`.
                return False
        i, j, d1, d2 = i+1, j+1, d1-1, d2-1
        if d1 > d2:
            return False
    return True
```

I'm primarily concerned about performance.

Comment: Specify what do you mean by "subsequence". Is `[1,1]` a subsequence of `[1,0,1]`? According to your code, it is. If you only want to consider continuous subsequences (eg. `[1,1]` is _not_ a subsequence of `[1,0,1]`), you can use a [string matching algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String-searching_algorithm#Single-pattern_algorithms). The items of the two lists can be viewed as characters of two strings.

Comment: `[1, 1]` is supposed to be a subsequence of `[1, 0, 1]`.

Comment: In that case, the complexity of your code is optimal. Some optimizations are admissible in specific cases, such as when repeatedly checking the same haystack. Then you might do some preprocessing and save the result, to be able to quickly check whether the needle can possibly be a subsequence or not. For example, make a set of elements of the haystack, and when the needle contains an element which is not in the set, it cannot be a subsequence of the haystack. This would be especially helpful if the haystack is long but contains few unique elements (many repeated elements).

Comment: Aah, thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 14):

## Review

- Testing

  > (I haven't rigorously tested it).

  Well you should write some test to ensure validity of the function. So even after changes you can be sure it will still work. [`doctest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/doctest.html) is a pretty nice module to use, and is a nice extension of your docstring
- Naming

  Variables should have descriptive names!

  `lst1`, `lst2` if it wasn't for that docstring I would not have known what is the subseq and the parent, so instead I propose to rename them to `needle` and `haystack` here the intent is more clear

  Same goes for `d1`, `d2`... I can see that they are the remaining length of the list, but it is hard to tell from the variable name.
- `for` is considered more Pythonic vs `while`

  For loops are Pythons greatest feature IMHO, they are easy to read and short to write

  You should start writing for loops instead of a while, "Loop like a native" might be an interesting talk to view
- Too many assignments in a line

  Might be preference, but I find this line hard to read:

  `i, j, d1, d2 = i+1, j+1, d1-1, d2-1`

  There are too many values with not enough descriptive names on this line

## Alternative

We can instead loop over the `haystack` and use slicing to compare the sliced `haystack` with the `needle`, lastly top it off with the `any` keyword and write some tests with the doctest module

```
import doctest

def is_subsequence(needle, haystack):
    """
    Finds if a list is a subsequence of another.

    * args
        needle: the candidate subsequence
        haystack: the parent list

    * returns
        boolean

    >>> is_subsequence([1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
    True
    >>> is_subsequence([1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 5, 6])
    False
    >>> is_subsequence([6], [1, 2, 3, 5, 6])
    True
    >>> is_subsequence([5, 6], [1, 2, 3, 5, 6])
    True
    >>> is_subsequence([[5, 6], 7], [1, 2, 3, [5, 6], 7])
    True
    >>> is_subsequence([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], [1, 2, 3, [5, 6], 7])
    False
    """
    return any(
        haystack[i:i+len(needle)] == needle
        for i in range(len(haystack) - len(needle) + 1)
    )

if __name__ == '__main__':
    doctest.testmod()
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I don't think `while` is compatible with the algorithm I chose. Also, the algorithm you used is **wrong**; it tests if the needle is a contiguous subsequence of the haystack, and that's not what I'm trying to do (my use case doesn't require the needle to be contiguous. e.g `[1, 1]` is a subsequence of `[1, 0, 1]`).

Comment: You should have clarified the problem statement in the Question, and if there were any tests, it would have been more obvious ;)

Comment: Indeed, that's one of the most important functions of tests: conveying to other users what results are expected.